# php delete text from a string between 2 words

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm using several strings named $text.
inside my $text string, I have a paragraph like this :

{slimbox single images/stories TEXT TEXT TEXT ... ge.jpg,}

all those paragraphs start with "{slimbox" and ends width "}"

what I'm trying to do is to delete all the text starting with "{slimbox" and ending width "}", including "{slimbox" and width "}".

I know how to use string replace and preg_replace, like this for example :

```
$text = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $text);
```

but I don't know how to delete an entire string by defing the 1st charachters and the lasts...

Basically, I have this as Input :

> {slimbox single
>   images/stories/INTERVIEW/KID_CREOLE/boys.jpg,images/stories/INTERVIEW/KID_CREOLE/00.jpg,;
>   images/stories/INTERVIEW/KID_CREOLE/creolecocosnafu2_80.jpg,images/stories/INTERVIEW/KID_CREOLE/creolecocosnafu2_80.jpg,;
>   images/stories/INTERVIEW/KID_CREOLE/creolevan5_28_80.jpg,images/stories/INTERVIEW/KID_CREOLE/creolevan5_28_80.jpg,;
>   images/stories/INTERVIEW/KID_CREOLE/kid-creole.jpg,images/stories/INTERVIEW/KID_CREOLE/kid-creole.jpg,;
>   images/stories/INTERVIEW/KID_CREOLE/darnelltrax.jpg,images/stories/INTERVIEW/KID_CREOLE/darnelltrax.jpg,;
>   images/stories/INTERVIEW/KID_CREOLE/kidguitar83stage.jpg,images/stories/INTERVIEW/KID_CREOLE/kidguitar83stage.jpg,}Sed
>   (saepe enim redeo ad Scipionem, cuius omnis sermo erat de amicitia)
>   querebatur, quod omnibus in rebus homines diligentiores essent; capras
>   et oves quot quisque haberet, dicere posse, amicos quot haberet, non
>   posse dicere et in illis quidem parandis adhibere curam, in amicis
>   eligendis neglegentis esse nec habere quasi signa quaedam et notas,
>   quibus eos qui ad amicitias essent idonei, iudicarent. Sunt igitur
>   firmi et stabiles et constantes eligendi; cuius generis est magna
>   penuria. Et iudicare difficile est sane nisi expertum; experiendum
>   autem est in ipsa amicitia. Ita praecurrit amicitia iudicium tollitque
>   experiendi potestatem.

and I need this as Output :

> Sed (saepe enim redeo ad Scipionem, cuius omnis sermo erat de
>   amicitia) querebatur, quod omnibus in rebus homines diligentiores
>   essent; capras et oves quot quisque haberet, dicere posse, amicos quot
>   haberet, non posse dicere et in illis quidem parandis adhibere curam,
>   in amicis eligendis neglegentis esse nec habere quasi signa quaedam et
>   notas, quibus eos qui ad amicitias essent idonei, iudicarent. Sunt
>   igitur firmi et stabiles et constantes eligendi; cuius generis est
>   magna penuria. Et iudicare difficile est sane nisi expertum;
>   experiendum autem est in ipsa amicitia. Ita praecurrit amicitia
>   iudicium tollitque experiendi potestatem.

can anybody help me with this ?

thanks a lot,

Comment: Please post a clear sample of input/output . i.e.: "i have this" and  "I need this"

Comment: check my answer. you don't need to replace, you can just get the matches to a new string.

Comment: Your "answer" `$new_text= preg_replace('/\{[^>]*\}/', '', $text);` is incorrect you aren't using `>` in your code so it make no sense to be looking for them.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = <<< LOB
{slimbox single images/stories/INTERVIEW/KID_CREOLE/boys.jpg,images/stories/INTERVIEW/KID_CREOLE/00.jpg,; images/stories/INTERVIEW/KID_CREOLE/creolecocosnafu2_80.jpg,images/stories/INTERVIEW/KID_CREOLE/creolecocosnafu2_80.jpg,; images/stories/INTERVIEW/KID_CREOLE/creolevan5_28_80.jpg,images/stories/INTERVIEW/KID_CREOLE/creolevan5_28_80.jpg,; images/stories/INTERVIEW/KID_CREOLE/kid-creole.jpg,images/stories/INTERVIEW/KID_CREOLE/kid-creole.jpg,; images/stories/INTERVIEW/KID_CREOLE/darnelltrax.jpg,images/stories/INTERVIEW/KID_CREOLE/darnelltrax.jpg,; images/stories/INTERVIEW/KID_CREOLE/kidguitar83stage.jpg,images/stories/INTERVIEW/KID_CREOLE/kidguitar83stage.jpg,}Sed (saepe enim redeo ad Scipionem, cuius omnis sermo erat de amicitia) querebatur, quod omnibus in rebus homines diligentiores essent; capras et oves quot quisque haberet, dicere posse, amicos quot haberet, non posse dicere et in illis quidem parandis adhibere curam, in amicis eligendis neglegentis esse nec habere quasi signa quaedam et notas, quibus eos qui ad amicitias essent idonei, iudicarent. Sunt igitur firmi et stabiles et constantes eligendi; cuius generis est magna penuria. Et iudicare difficile est sane nisi expertum; experiendum autem est in ipsa amicitia. Ita praecurrit amicitia iudicium tollitque experiendi potestatem.
LOB;

preg_match_all('/}(.*?)$/sim', $string , $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
echo $matches[1][0];
```

Output:

```
Sed (saepe enim redeo ad Scipionem, cuius omnis sermo erat de amicitia) querebatur, quod omnibus in rebus homines diligentiores essent; capras et oves quot quisque haberet, dicere posse, amicos quot haberet, non posse dicere et in illis quidem parandis adhibere curam, in amicis eligendis neglegentis esse nec habere quasi signa quaedam et notas, quibus eos qui ad amicitias essent idonei, iudicarent. Sunt igitur firmi et stabiles et constantes eligendi; cuius generis est magna penuria. Et iudicare difficile est sane nisi expertum; experiendum autem est in ipsa amicitia. Ita praecurrit amicitia iudicium tollitque experiendi potestatem.
```

---

Demo

http://ideone.com/fPgv52